# wxWidgets - wxThread

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm developing an application which needs to have a permanent server socket listening, so I put it in a thread, here there is the class I've written for it:

```
class listenThread : public wxThread
{
    public:
        listenThread(MyFrame *h) : wxThread() { handler = h; };
        virtual void * Entry();
    private:
        MyFrame *handler;
};

void *listenThread::Entry()
{
    handler->sockConvs[nconvs] = handler->sockServer->Accept();

    if(handler->sockConvs[handler->nconvs]->IsConnected() && handler->nconvs < 10)
    {
    handler->frames[handler->nconvs] = new MyFrame(NULL);
    handler->frames[handler->nconvs++]->Show();
    }
}
```

The class MyFrame handler of Thread:

```
class MyFrame : public wxFrame
{
    friend class listenThread;

    public:

           /* other stuff ... */

    private:
           /* other stuff ... */

    private:
        listenThread *myThread;

        // Both initialized in MyFrame class constructor
        wxSocketServer *sockServer;
        wxIPV4address addr;

        wxSocketBase *sockConvs[10];
        MyFrame *frames[10];
        int nconvs;
};
```

Now the problem is that when a client connects to my Application, the listening thread receives this incoming connection (for each connection, obiviusly, it uses a different SocketBase from sockConvs array) and allocates (as you can see) a new MyFrame.
BUT! at the end of the Entry method my new Frame is closed. Why?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this could be related to the fact that you are not supposed to make any GUI calls in secondary threads, this is explained more fully in the documentation of [wxThread](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_thread.html#thread_secondary). You probably ought to post an event back to your main thread and create the frame there.